# what does it mean to have a dot after table name when using insert into in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I see this statement in the code
 `INSERT INTO question.surveykey (dateposted,entryCount) VALUES ('$date',0)`,

Shouldn't it be a table name after insert into statement? What does it mean to have a dot after that?

Comment: `question` appears to be the database name, and `surveykey` seems to be the table name.

Comment: I get it now, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find plenty of examples in the manual regarding [identifier qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

> You can refer to a table within the default database as `tbl_name`, or as `db_name.tbl_name` to specify a database explicitly.

Without the explicit mention of a database name, the default database is used (when you're on the console, you'd set the default database by entering `use db_name`).

This comes in handy when you've got a seed file that populates tables across multiple databases, or if you're in one database (using console) and you want to operate on a table in another.